# Task based Asynchronous Patterns in Loops

Tags: .net, loops, asynchronous, tap

I need to make BuildReports() Asynchronous because this Function can take several minutes to complete depending on the number of reports it has to create. It is called by btnClearAll_Click() that I added ‘Async’ and ‘Await’ too. I’ve added ‘Async’ to BuildReports() and tried numerous placements for ‘Await’ including using on the If-Then-Else’ statement prior to the loop. I also tried ‘Awaitable’ for the datatable (dt) created in reportComponent.CreatePDF() (a SQL Select query). ClearAll() is Synchronous.

So I need some help here, I’ve read numerous articles on this but I missing something. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
Private Async Sub btnClearAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearAll.Click

    Await BuildReports()

    ClearAll()

End Sub

Private Async Function BuildReports() As Task

    Try
        Dim reportComponent As New ReportComponent(CStr(Session("UserConnectionString")))
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        dt = reportComponent.CreatePDF()

        If dt IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim ScheduleDto As New ScheduleDto()
            Dim scheduleDtoList As New List(Of ScheduleDto)()
            Dim report1 As Telerik.Reporting.Report = Nothing

            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                    If row IsNot Nothing Then
                       ScheduleDto.Encounter_code = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Encounter_code").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.CaseNumber = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("CaseNumber").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.Case_Name = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Case_Name").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.DOS = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("DOS").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.Provider = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Provider").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.Discipline = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Discipline").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.Episode = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Episode").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.ReportType = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("ReportType").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.DocumentName = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("Document_Name").ToString
                        ScheduleDto.ItemType = dt.Rows.Item(i).Item("ItemType").ToString

                        scheduleDtoList.Add(ScheduleDto)
                        report1 = reportComponent.GetReport(ScheduleDto, ScheduleDto.ReportType, CStr(Session("UserConnectionString")))
                       If (report1 IsNot Nothing) Then
                            Dim pdfPath As String = ""
                            Dim DownloadReport As New DownloadReports()
                       DownloadReport.DownloadReport(report1, ScheduleDto, ScheduleDto.DocumentName, ScheduleDto.ReportType, pdfPath) 
                       reportComponent.FinalizeNow(ScheduleDto.Encounter_code)

                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next

        Else : Return
        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message & " : Build_Reports")
    Finally
    End Try


End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler should be giving you an error with that code, because `BuildReports` is marked as `Async` but is not using `Await`.

Note that "asynchronous" does **not** mean "run on a background thread". Thus, there is no way to "make" synchronous code asynchronous; the code itself is synchronous or asynchronous by nature.

So, for example, if you had naturally-asynchronous database operations (e.g., using Entity Framework), then you could have a naturally-asynchronous `BuildReports`. However, the `DataTable` API is not amenable to asynchrony, so `DataTable` does not have asynchronous APIs at all. It is firmly stuck in the synchronous world.

In your particular case, it's probably best to run your existing *synchronous* code on a background thread, which can be done with `Task.Run`. You can then *consume* it asynchronously:

```
Private Async Sub btnClearAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearAll.Click
    Await Task.Run(Function() BuildReports())
    ClearAll()
End Sub

Private Sub BuildReports()
...
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Making the changes you suggested I'm getting "Expression does not produce a value" in line: Await Task.Run(Function() BuildReports()). Any ideas?

Comment: @JackW9653: Sorry, that should be an anonymous `Sub`, not `Function`.

Comment: Works Perfectly! Thanks @Stephen. I've read several of your articles, can you suggest a good source of explanation for using Async/Await on future projects? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @JackW9653: If you haven't already read them, I usually recommend my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) blog post and [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) MSDN article.

Comment: I'm getting some odd errors in some of the Functions called from BuildReports(), of course these all worked previously. I'm using:    Private Async Sub btnClearAll_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClearAll.Click
        Await Task.Run(Sub() BuildReports())
        ClearAll()
    End Sub
Anything wrong here? I'm using VS2015.

Comment: @JackW9653: I don't see anything wrong in that code. Try to reduce the code down to the minimal code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: BuildReports() calls DownloadReports.DownloadReports() that uses data in the web.config and a Session variable to build a path. Since BuildReports() is running on a background thread can I read from the web.config or Session variables?

Comment: @JackW9653: `web.config`, yes. Session, no.

Comment: if I assign a variable to the Session before the Await will that carry through to the Background thread?

Comment: @JackW9653: Not safely. "Session" only makes sense within a request context, and `Task.Run` explicitly *leaves* the request context.

Comment: Any suggestions? I need a path that is dependent on a Session as a component.

Comment: @JackW9653: Since this is an ASP.NET app, you should remove the `Task.Run` completely. Just have `btnClearAll_Click` call `BuildReports` and then `ClearAll`.

Comment: That's what I had to begin with but since BuildReports takes several minutes to process I wanted to make that Asynchronous so it could process without holding up ClearAll.

Comment: @JackW9653: You can't run more than one thread in a request context. You'll have to decide whether to run them one at a time, or run one of them outside the request context. Personally, I strongly prefer one at a time, since parallel code in ASP.NET is almost always a mistake.

Comment: Do I need to do anything differently on the call to BuildReports to run it outside the request context? It just takes to long to run one at a time.

Comment: @JackW9653: My answer would run it outside the request context and have the request (asynchronously) wait for it to complete. If you're asking about fire-and-forget on ASP.NET, then you [have to choose between extremely dangerous or extremely complex](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).